# getting user details using firebase auth where condition is multiple phoneNumbers

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to retrieve users using phoneNumber where phoneNumber is multiple I would say an array of phoneNumber I want to get the users response using this. I only know how to retrieve using a single number.

```
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber('+91555555555')
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

and I have an array of phoneNumbers that is

```
['+915555555555','+916666445555','+917778886655',+91555598668']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to bulk retrieve users by phone number.  You will have to iterate the array and call `getUserByPhoneNumber` for each one individually.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: This feature is currently under development: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/pull/726. Keep an eye on the above PR for status updates.